# Django model got an unexpected keyward argument

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to save crawling data into db, but it has unexpected keyword argument error.

```
reviewData() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reviewText'
```

some parts of **crawling.py**

```
for j in range(review_cnt):
    if soup.select_one(f'li:nth-child({j+1}) > div._1Z_GL > div.PVBo8 > a > span') != None:
        if(len(soup.select(f'li:nth-child({j+1}) > div._1Z_GL > div.PVBo8 > a > span'))) == 2:
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'li:nth-child({j+1}) > div._1Z_GL > div.PVBo8 > a').send_keys(Keys.ENTER) 
            current_page = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(current_page, 'html.parser')  
            time.sleep(1)                                         
            review_text = soup.select_one(f'li:nth-child({j+1}) > div._1Z_GL > div.PVBo8 > a > span').text.strip() #텍스트 추출 
            star_rate = soup.select_one(f'li:nth-child({j+1}) > div._1Z_GL > div._1ZcDn > div._3D_HC > span._2tObC').text
            review_data.append((place_name, review_text, star_rate))
            review_obj = {
                'place' : place_name,
                'review' : review_text,
                'rate' : star_rate
                }
                review_dict.append(review_obj)
for item in review_dict:
  reviewData(placeName = item['place'], reviewText = item['review'], starRate = item['rate']).save() #this line has error
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class reviewData(models.Model):
    placeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reviewText = models.TextField
    starRate = models.FloatField
```

I don't know where to fix.
Should I add something more?

Comment: did you migrate your model

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because you forgot the parenthesis

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class reviewData(models.Model):
    placeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reviewText = models.TextField()
    starRate = models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 1):

The fields in your model need to be instances of `Field`, not just a reference to the type (ie. it needs to be called with `()`)

```
class reviewData(models.Model):
    # placeName is an instance of Field which is correct (called with ())
    placeName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # reviewText is a reference to a type (not called with `()`)
    reviewText = models.TextField
    # starRate is also just a reference to type instead of instance
    starRate = models.FloatField
```

your model needs to look as follows (+applying PEP8 rules for variable names - classes are `CamelCase` starting with capital letters, attributes should be `snake_case`)

```
class ReviewData(models.Model):
    place_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    review_text = models.TextField()
    star_rate = models.FloatField()
```